# Is There Any Optimization Scheduler in Solr?

Tags: solr

I want to optimize the Solr Server at a specific time(ex.midnight) on daily basis. Is there any way to schedule the optimization job in Solr?.. Is there any Quartz like scheduling API available in Solr?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not anything built into Solr. But you can run an optimize on your index by issuing the following Curl statement:

```
 curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update?optimize=true&maxSegments=10&waitFlush=false'
```

Please be sure to change the Url and parameters as necessary for your environment. You can see more details on the options on the Solr Wiki - [UpdateXMLMessage - commit & optimize](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22) page.

Then you can schedule this curl command to be called by various ways; for example a cron job or via Quartz.

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily modify URL in my [DIH Scheduler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling), which is [supposed to be included in Solr 4.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2305).

It basically allows Solr web app to spawn a separate thread (as the app is started on a server) that fires GET requests periodically, at specified intervals.

You can find the source on Google Code, [here](http://code.google.com/p/solr-data-import-scheduler/).